# youtube-dl freezing whenever the folder is loading(?)

Tags: youtube-dl

My youtube-dl keeps freezing/ stopping its download whenever my folders are loading(? not sure if that is the correct phrase for this), as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJed.jpg).

Every time this happens, I will need to restart my computer in order to fix this, is there anyway to solve this problem permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried going to properties of my `Downloads` folder, then go to `customise` and ticked the `Also apply this template to all subfolders`. And it seemed to have work currently, will be updated if the issues keep appearing.